# What are the conditions on two multivariate real polynomials $f$ and $g$ so that their zero sets are similar?

Tags: real-algebraic-geometry, multivariate-polynomial

Basically what the title says. Let $f$ and $g$ be two polynomials with real coefficients of degree $m$, in $n$ real variables. The solutions of the equation $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = 0$ then define a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. We can now apply a similarity transformation $A$ to each tuple $x\ = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and obtain a new hypersurface consisting of the points $Ax$. Now let $g$ be the polynomial that has precisely $Ax$ as its zero set. How do you now obtain $g$ from $f$?

My understanding so far is that since $A$ is a similarity transformation, it must be a scalar multiple of an orthogonal transformation. For simplicity, we can assume the scalar to be equal to one. There now needs to be a way to translate this $\text{O}(n)$ action on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to some action on the polynomial ring containing $f$ and $g$ which maps $f$ onto $g$, but i have no idea what this action would look like.

For some context: This question arises from physics, where the surface of the eight-dimensional state space of a three-level quantum system can be described by a polynomial equation of degree 3, in 8 variables. I am currently studying 3 and 4 dimensional sections of this space, and there are some sections which have the same shape, despite being described by different equations. Especially, the equations

$3(x^2+y^2+z^2)-6\sqrt{3}xyz = 0$

and

$3(x^2+y^2+z^2)-3\sqrt{3}x(y^2-z^2) = 0$

both describe the same shape, according to the authors of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.4427.pdf). However, the only similarity between these two equations i could find was that the sum of the absolute values of the coefficients is the same for both of them.

Answer (score 1):

If $f,g$ are polynomials with $f(x)=0$ equivalent to $g(Ax)=0$ for an invertible transformation $A$, then $g=f(A^{-1}x)$.

In your case, the substitution $y\mapsto \frac{y-z}{\sqrt{2}}, z\mapsto \frac{y+z}{\sqrt{2}}$ takes the first equation to the second.

Comment: That makes sense to me, classic example of an answer so simple i didn't even consider it to begin with. What is still somewhat unclear to me is how exactly the orthogonal group seems to act on the space of polynomials, and especially, if there is an algorithmic procedure to figure out if two  arbitrary polynomials have similar zero sets.

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "how exactly the orthogonal group acts"? If you're looking to describe the action on a polynomial, the orthogonal group acts by linear transformations, so it gives you a list of substitutions $x_i\mapsto\sum a_{ij} x_j$ which you plug in to polynomials to see where they go under the action. I'm not sure about the second question, but I suspect it is difficult.

Comment: I guess i was asking if there was a more abstract way to study this action, similar to the adjoint representation of $\text{SU}(n)/\mathbb{Z}_n$ in terms of a subgroup of $\text{O}(n^2-1)$.

Comment: Sure, there's lots of abstract ways to study this action. You can take a vector space of polynomials and treat it as a representation of the orthogonal group; you can take (the appropriate) quotient to decompose in to orbits; I'm sure there are more. Perhaps if you have a more specific question you can make a new post. (This is partly for visibility reasons - you won't get a lot of new eyes on your question if it's just in these comments.)